# complex VBA function with excel IF, index, match function

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Please help me to create VBA function wtih excel IF, index, match function. here is my excel function :

```
=IF(INDEX(Grid!$B$3:$G$6,MATCH('Sal-Data'!$A2,Grid!$A$3:$A$6,0),MATCH('Sal-Data'!$B2+1,Grid!$B$2:$G$2,0))=0,$B2,$B2+1)
```

I have added VBA codes here ,which is not working, I want a result for next Level from Grid Sheet. example if current Grid in Sheet"Sal-data" for Emp "b" is 2 then new Grid would be 3, but value in "Grid" sheet for "b" Grid 3 is 0 (zero) then Grid should not be increase. In this case if "b" current grid is 3 then b's next grid may get 4 , but grid 4 value is 0 then "b"s grid should not increase as there is no value.

Here is my VBA coding :

```
Public Function NGrid(rData As Range, rBudCode As Range, rMo As Range, budgetcode As Variant, mo As Variant)
Dim rw As Variant
Dim col As Variant
    With Application
        col = .Match(budgetcode+1, rBudCode, 0)
        rw = .Match(mo, rMo, 0)
        NGrid = .Index(rData, col, rw)

If NGrid= 0 Then
 With Application
col = .Match(budgetcode, rBudCode, 0)
        rw = .Match(mo, rMo, 0)
        NGrid = .Index(rData, col, rw)
Else
With Application
col = .Match(budgetcode+1, rBudCode, 0)
        rw = .Match(mo, rMo, 0)
        NGrid = .Index(rData, col, rw)
End if 
End with 
End Function
```

---

```
 Excel sheet name : Grid

    1   2   3   4   5   6
a   10  11  12  13  0   0
b   20  21  22  0   0   0
c   30  31  32  33  34  0
d   40  41  42  0   0   0


Excel sheet name : Sal-Data

Emp grid    New grid
a   4   = NGrid (...) required VBA function
a   2   
b   1   
b   2
```

Than you in advance.

Comment: What is wrong with the code, where does it error and what error is thrown?

Comment: As a start, get rid of the two `With Application` statements within your `If` block - they aren't needed, and you don't have matching `End With` statements for them anyway so the code won't compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One, you do not need the Else as it just repeats the first.

Two, every `With` needs an `End With`, in this case the other `With Application` are not needed.

Three, Index is `Row,Column` not `Column,Row`

```
Public Function NGrid(rData As Range, rBudCode As Range, rMo As Range, budgetcode As Variant, mo As Variant)
Dim rw As Long
Dim col As Long

With Application
    col = .Match(budgetcode + 1, rBudCode, 0)
    rw = .Match(mo, rMo, 0)
    NGrid = .Index(rData, rw, col)
    If NGrid = 0 Then
        col = .Match(budgetcode, rBudCode, 0)
        rw = .Match(mo, rMo, 0)
        NGrid = .Index(rData, rw, col)
    End If
End With
End Function
```

Then make sure you include the title row and column in rData:

```
=NGrid(Grid!$A$1:$G$5,Grid!$A$1:$G$1,Grid!$A$1:$A$5,B2,A2)
```

[image]

---

This allows the use of just the range of the grid, no need to specify the first row and column differently:

```
Public Function NGrid(rData As Range, budgetcode As Variant, mo As Variant)
Dim rw As Long
Dim col As Long
Dim rBudCode As Range
Dim rMo As Range
With Application
    Set rBudCode = rData.Rows(1)
    Set rMo = rData.Columns(1)
    col = .Match(budgetcode + 1, rBudCode, 0)
    rw = .Match(mo, rMo, 0)
    NGrid = .Index(rData, rw, col)
    If NGrid = 0 Then
        NGrid = .Index(rData, rw, col - 1)
    End If
End With
End Function
```

So the above formula would be:

```
=NGrid(Grid!$A$1:$G$5,B2,A2)
```

[image]

---

Grid sheet: for reference

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

```
Public Function NGrid(rData As Range, rBudCode As Range, rMo As Range, budgetcode As Variant, mo As Variant)
    Dim rw As Variant, col As Variant

    With Application
        col = .Match(budgetcode + 1, rBudCode, 0)
        rw = .Match(mo, rMo, 0)

        If Not IsError(rw) Then
            If Not IsError(col) Then
                NGrid = .Index(rData, col, rw)
                If NGrid = 0 Then
                    col = .Match(budgetcode, rBudCode, 0)
                    If Not IsError(col) Then
                        NGrid = .Index(rData, col, rw)
                    Else
                        NGrid = "budget?" 'no col match
                    End If
                End If
            Else
                NGrid = "budget+1?" 'no col match on +1
            End If
        Else
            NGrid = "mo?" 'no row match
        End If
    End With

End Function
```

If your source data always has the lookups in the first column and row then you really only need to pass in a single range: you can pick out the lookup ranges from that using `.Rows(1)` and `.Columns(1)`